# Looking for Excel formula to find and compare over multiple workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am looking for an excel 2010 formula that will enable me to check data over multiple workbooks.

I have a workbook (staff) where i have a list of all the staff currently employed.

I have multiple workbooks per department where each department has to account for their staff (dept1, dept2, dept3, dept4 etc).

Is there a formula that i can use to ensure that all staff have been accounted for?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

- In a summary worksheet, use the `INDIRECT` function in combination with a table of path, workbook, sheet, and sum cell name for each department. The INDIRECT function returns the reference specified by a string: For example, if cell A1 contains the string "Sheet1!D19", then =INDIRECT(A1) will give the value in cell D19 of Sheet1.

So, what you need is a set of cells in the summary sheet that contains references to the cell or cells in each department workbook that sum up the staffing for the department. The table to construct those references, and the accompanying formulas, might look like this.

[image: Example of summary table using the INDIRECT function]

The formulas for each department's staffing total, shown in column F of the picture, evaluate to valid cell references in the departmental workbooks. I've chosen to build the formulas from references in a table in order to have flexibility - only the table entries must be modified if, for example, the list of workbooks that need be included changes, rather than the formulas themselves.

These formulas will update only when the workbooks they refer to are open; if a department's workbook is closed, the staffing total formula for that department in the summary sheet will return a #REF! error when it is recalculated value. In other words, you can't pull data from a closed workbook.

- Use a VBA function or subroutine that is able to extract data from a closed workbook.

There a number of different approaches to do this, including [this function](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/), from John Walkenbach's web site, which only works when used in a VBA procedure and [this one](http://numbermonger.com/2012/02/11/excel-pull-function-creating-dynamic-links-to-closed-workbooks/) which is directly usable in a worksheet. I have tested both and they work as claimed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I don't understand the sum staff? Maybe I did not express my question correctly. I have a list of my names in one workbook. I have to look for this name across multiple workbooks(departments) and retur the department next to the name. Any help would be much appreciated.